# How to replace the space between two words with a hyphen if the first and last letter of the two words matches a particular pattern?

Tags: lua, replace

I'm working with a language which has some particular rules about spelling. When words are put together, they do not have spaces, but occasionally use `'` or `-` to `-` distinguish where one word begins and another ends, in the rare cases where confusion can occur.

I have the words currently displayed with spaces between then, e.g.:

```
The cat caught the mouse.
```

However, I need to remove the spaces, e.g.:

```
Thecatcaughtthemouse.
```

Before these spaces can be removed though, the rules regarding the placement of `'` and `-` must be considered:

first, if the first letter of a word (which also follows another word) begins with a vowel (`a`, `a`, `á`, `à`, `ǎ`, `ā`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `e`, `é`, `è`, `ě`, `ē`, `i`, `i`, `í`, `ì`, `ǐ`, `ī`, `o`, `o`, `ó`, `ò`, `ǒ`, `ō`, `u`, `u`, `ú`, `ù`, `ǔ`, `ü`, `ǘ`, `ǜ`, `ǚ`, `ǖ`, or `ū`), then replace the space with a `'` (between words), e.g.:

```
The cat ate the sandwich and the ice cream.
```

This becomes:

```
Thecat'atethesandwichandthe'icecream.
```

This does not apply to words at the beginning of the sentence.

Next, if the last letter of a word begins with "a", "u", or "ü" (`a`, `a`, `á`, `à`, `ǎ`, `ā`, `u`, `u`, `ú`, `ù`, `ǔ`, `ü`, `ǘ`, `ǜ`, `ǚ`, `ǖ`, or `ū`) and next word in the sentences begins with "n", then replace the space with a `-` (between words), e.g.:

```
The people from Australia needed a car to visit the plateau near the river.
```

This becomes:

```
Thepeoplefrom'Australia-needed'acartovisittheplateau-neartheriver.
```

Finally, if the last letter of a word ends with "n" and the next word in the sentence begins with "g", then replace the space with a `-` (between words), e.g.:

```
The Australian grasshopper was lost in the overgrown grove.
```

This becomes:

```
The'Australian-grasshopperwaslostinthe'overgrown-grove.
```

How can I replace the spaces between words matching these patterns with `'` and `-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say just why you're doing this.  Let's hope it's not a homework problem.

Suppose that a word ends with a vowel and the next begins with 'f' or 't', and I want to replace the space with a star, I write

```
sentence:gsub('([aeiouy])%s+([ft])', '%1*%2')
```

You can take it from there.

Comment: And, if you Unicode processing is required, UTF-8 capable `gsub` is implemented in [slnunicode](http://files.luaforge.net/releases/sln/slnunicode).